# C# debug and result changing

Tags: c#

I found this code in interview tasks. The result depends on debug. Why `Value` changes in debug mode? Please explain how it's work.

```
static IEnumerable<int> Square(IEnumerable<int> a)
{
    foreach (var r in a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r * r);
        yield return r * r;
    }
}
class Wrap
{
    private static int init = 0;
    public int Value1
    {
        get { return ++init; }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var w = new Wrap();
    var wraps = new Wrap[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < wraps.Length; i++)
    {
        wraps[i] = w;
    }
    var values = wraps.Select(x => x.Value1);
    var results = Square(values);
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var r in results)
    {
        count++;
        sum += r;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", count);
    Console.WriteLine("Sum {0}", sum);

    Console.WriteLine("Count {0}", results.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("Sum {0}", results.Sum());
}
```

For example:
Normal output without any breakpoint

> 1
>       4
>       9
>       Count 3
>       Sum 14
>       16
>       25
>       36
>       Count 3
>       49
>       64
>       81
>       Sum 194

But if you should place for example breakpoint near `wraps[i] = w;` and expand values for several times

[image]

You can get something like:

> 16
>   25
>   36
>   Count 3
>   Sum 77
>   49
>   64
>   81
>   Count 3
>   100
>   121
>   144
>   Sum 365

Or even bigger. The result depends on the number of times that you observed the values of the variables in debug mode. Why?

I am running in the debugger, stepping through code and examining properties

Comment: It doesn't help that you don't say what results you *do* see in each case, either. (And putting the whole thing in a [mcve] we could just copy/paste/compile and run would help too - there's no point in *everyone who wants to reproduce the problem* having to add the containing class and using directives.)

Comment: Also note that there's a difference between "building in debug mode", "running in the debugger without breaking" and "running in the debugger, stepping through code and examining properties" - which of them are you referring to?

Comment: Think about what Value1 does. What happens if you check its value in the middle of the run?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, but if i should add for example Value1 to Watch. It does not change. Watch and checking value in middle run they have different functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint and use the watch window to observer `Value1`, the debugger *accesses this property*.

By accessing `Value1`, the getter code is executed, hence

```
get { return ++init; }
```

increases `init` by `1`.